# Set gravity of videoview to center without taking any parent view

Tags: android

I want to set the gravity of a vidoeview to center without taking any parent view of that.Currently it playing in top of the screen.I want it to play in the center.I cannot take any parent of videoview as it is creating issue because i am using this view in viewflipper which contains videos,images,pdf etc.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.
My xml is:-

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <VideoView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/test_vide_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1"

     />
```

Comment: try this android:layout_gravity="center"

Comment: I tried this but not working

Comment: Your video frame size?

Comment: Video was created in landscape mode and i am trying to play it in portrait mode

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14960240/1765530

Comment: this is also not working..